# Are there any context-oriented programming language, and what's their use for?

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms

I heard someone talking about Context-Oriented Programming, so I googled it to found out what that means, and it seems like a new paradigm of programming, but also all I found are academic papers talking about the concept.

So I would like to know if there's any language that implements context-orientation and what is this good for?

Comment: You can take a look at [Subjective-C](https://released.info.ucl.ac.be/Tools/Subjective-C)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COP is a programming paradigm supporting software adaptation to the execution context.

It's an alternative to the use of hard-coded conditional statements spread over the application to encode context-dependent behavior.

In the years several COP extensions to various languages have been proposed:

- [ContextJ](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/Cop/wiki/ContextJ) and [JCop](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/Cop/wiki/JCop) for Java
- [Context Erlang](http://www.guidosalvaneschi.com/wp/software/contexterlang/) for Erlang
- [ContextL](https://common-lisp.net/project/closer/contextl.html) for Common Lisp (the first COP extension to a programming language)
- [SubjectiveC](https://released.info.ucl.ac.be/Tools/Subjective-C) for Objective C
- ContextS for Smalltalk
- [PyContext](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyContext) for Python
- [ContextR](https://github.com/schmidt/contextr/) for Ruby
- [ContextJS](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/Cop/wiki/ContextJS) for Javascript

and probably many others.

Each concrete language design and implementation comes with different variations of the features of the COP paradigm. For further details you can see [A Comparison of Context-oriented
Programming Languages](http://soft.vub.ac.be/cop09/papers/a6-appeltauer.pdf) (Malte Appeltauer, Robert Hirschfeld, Michael Haupt, Jens Lincke, Michael Perscheid - 2010).

Also a good introduction / starting point is [Context-oriented Programming](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2008_03/article4/) (Robert Hirschfeld, Pascal Costanza, Oscar Nierstrasz) or [Context-Oriented Programming: A Programming Paradigm for Autonomic Systems](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0069.pdf) (Guido Salvaneschi, Carlo Ghezzi, Matteo Pradella - 2013).

Comment: The most updated reference (2012) is probably this survey: [Context-oriented programming: A software engineering perspective](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2222313).